# try to normalize data ,but got TypeError: unhashable type

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to normalize my data frame using the first row of stock price. Below are my normalize function.

```
def get_data(symbols, dates, addSPY=True, colname = 'Adj. Close'):
"""Read stock data (adjusted close) for given symbols from CSV files."""
##df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)

for symbol in symbols:
    save_place = get_data(symbol)
    df = pd.read_csv(save_place, index_col='Date',
        parse_dates=True, usecols=['Date', colname], na_values=['nan'])
    df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={colname: symbol})
    df = df.join(df_temp)

return df

def normalize_data(df):
    """Normalize stock price using the first row of dataframe """
    print(df)
    return df/df[0,:]
     Adj. Close

Date                       
2016-06-09           153.42
2016-06-08            154.0
2016-06-07           153.33
2016-06-06           152.73
2016-06-03           152.89
2016-06-02            153.5
2016-06-01           152.51
2016-05-31           153.74
2016-05-27           152.84
2016-05-26           152.44
2016-05-25           151.69
```

the error is:

```
  File "util.py", line 40, in normalize_data
    return df/df[0,:]
  File "C:\Users\fange\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1992, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\fange\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1999, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\fange\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1343, in _get_item_cache
    res = cache.get(item)
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Comment: try `df.div(df.iloc[0], axis=1)`

Comment: @EdChum  Could not operate array(['153.42'], dtype=object) with block values index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are starting with a `pd.DataFrame` with a single `column`, `'Adj.Close'`:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df.squeeze()) # alternatively to df.squeeze(), you could use df.loc[:, 'Adj. Close']

            Adj. Close
Date                  
2016-06-09      153.42
2016-06-08      154.00
2016-06-07      153.33
2016-06-06      152.73
2016-06-03      152.89
2016-06-02      153.50
2016-06-01      152.51
2016-05-31      153.74
2016-05-27      152.84
2016-05-26      152.44
2016-05-25      151.69
```

using

```
s.div(s.iloc[0])
```

yields:

```
            Adj. Close
Date                  
2016-06-09    1.000000
2016-06-08    1.003780
2016-06-07    0.999413
2016-06-06    0.995503
2016-06-03    0.996545
2016-06-02    1.000521
2016-06-01    0.994069
2016-05-31    1.002086
2016-05-27    0.996220
2016-05-26    0.993612
2016-05-25    0.988724
```

Comment: still getting the error  Could not operate array(['153.42'], dtype=object) with block values index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: See updated answer. you may need to use `pd.to_numeric` first, looks like your data are `string` because it says `dtype=object`.

Comment: is there any way to convert a data type to series?    df = df.iloc[:,0]
    print(df)
    df = pd.to_numeric(df)
    return df.div(df.iloc[0]) Got value Error unable to parse string

Comment: See updated, now assuming you are starting with a `pd.DataFrame` with two columns: `[ 'Date', 'Adj.Close']`

Comment: I print the columns (    print(df.columns.values)
). it only contains ['Adj. Close']. See the above edited for how the dataframe is generated. Sorry, I am new to panda.

Comment: No problem, so you already have `'Date'` as index. Will update answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank for your efforts. Still ValueError: Unable to parse string

Comment: What does df.reset_index().info() show after pd.to_numeric()?

Comment: exception happened when it tried to convert to numeric. 
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 598, in pandas.lib.maybe_convert_numeric (pandas\lib.c:53719)

ValueError: Unable to parse string

Comment: You can use `pd.to_numeric(errors='coerce')` to convert all strings to missing values. You should also take a look at the data to see why there are values that can't be converted to float. See `to_numeric` docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html